# Induced group homomorphism $\text{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z}) \twoheadrightarrow \text{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})$ surjective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, number-theory, determinant

Let $n, m > 1$. The map $\mathbb{Z} \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, of reduction mod $m$, induces a group homomorphism $F: \text{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z}) \to \text{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})$. My question is, is $F$ surjective or not?

Comment: Yes.  This is proved in Shimura's book "Introduction to the Arithmetic Theory of Automorphic Functions." I don't have a copy in front of me to find the page.

Comment: related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321765/why-is-the-quotient-map-sl-n-mathbbz-to-sl-n-mathbbz-p-mathbb-z-is-s

Comment: Another source for a proof is Lemma 6.3.10 of Henri Cohen's "Number Theory, Volume 1: Tools and Diophantine Equations."

Comment: As @KCd has said, this is Lemma 1.38 in Shimura's book, where it is proven using elementary divisor theory. I feel that there should be a more elementary proof.

Comment: @KCd Isn't this a duplicate of that related question?

Comment: @6005, yes, indeed it is!  When I read that related question before I thought the q there was prime, which it need not be.

Answer (score -1):

This turned out to be a *non-example*.  I'm leaving it up for posterity as a CW answer.

---

As it turns out, the answer is no.  The smallest counterexample I can think of is as follows: we note that
$$
\pmatrix{2&1&1\\1&2&1\\1&1&2} \in SL_n(\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z)
$$
However, this matrix is not the reduction mod $3$ of any element of $SL_n(\Bbb Z)$.

Comment: To be sure, I haven't checked all members of the equivalence class of this element, so I'm not *certain* that this is a counterexample after all.

Comment: I found a matrix in $SL_n(\mathbb Z)$ reducing to this one: $$\pmatrix{-1&1&1\\1&-1&-2\\-2&1&-1} \in SL_n(\mathbb Z)$$
Unfortunately, I had no more sophisticated method than "check the determinant of a lot of matrices"

Comment: Replacing one of the $1$ by a $4$ also works.