# Is the natural homomorphism $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})\to SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$ onto?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, automorphic-forms

**EDIT**: Let $N\geq 2$ be a natural number. Consider the natural group homomorphism
$$SL_2(\mathbb{Z})\to SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$$
given by reduction modulo $N$.

**Is it onto?** If not is anything known about its image?

Comment: Hint: what happens to the determinant?

Comment: Oops... Got it. Thanks! Then probably I have to modify the question and replace $GL_2$ by $SL_2$.

Comment: Then yes, this map is well-known to be onto. This was probably asked on this website, too.

Comment: Indeed, one of the related questions shown is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409197/induced-group-homomorphism-textsl-n-mathbbz-twoheadrightarrow-textsl

Comment: Given $\pmatrix{a&0\\0&d} \in SL_2(\Bbb{Z}/N\Bbb{Z})$ It is not hard to find a matrix in $SL_2(\Bbb{Z})$ it is the reduction of. Then check that $\pmatrix{a&0\\0&d},\pmatrix{1&1\\0&1},\pmatrix{1&0\\1&1}$ generate $SL_2(\Bbb{Z}/N\Bbb{Z})$.